# jQuery filter by slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright, seems like I'm always coming here for help because I'm missing something stupid. So for my class I'm attempting to use JavaScript and jQuery to create a slider that fades out items that are above the value specified by the slider, so for example if an item cost 8 dollars and the slider is set to 7, everything that costs over 8 dollars fades out. So here's the code of the entire page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>The Candy Bar</title>
<link href="candycss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="range.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.--><script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script><script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/aguafina-script:n4:default;alegreya:n4,i4,n7:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.ndd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/dragdrop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
        function printValue(sliderID, textbox) {
            var x = document.getElementById(textbox);
            var y = document.getElementById(sliderID);
            x.value = y.value;
        }

        window.onload = function() { printValue('slider', 'rangeValue') }
</script>
<script>
// Set price data for candy

    $('#candy1').data({ id:1, price:1 });
    $('#candy2').data({ id:2, price:2 });
    $('#candy3').data({ id:3, price:3 });
    $('#candy4').data({ id:4, price:4 });
    $('#candy5').data({ id:5, price:5 });
    $('#candy6').data({ id:6, price:6 });
    $('#candy7').data({ id:7, price:7 });
    $('#candy8').data({ id:8, price:8 });

// Link range to candy
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var theValue;

        $("#slider").change(function (){
            theValue = $('#rangeValue').val();
            filterItems(theValue);
        });
    });

    function filterItems(priceCriteria){
        $.each($('#gallery div'), function(i, item){
            $item = $(item); 
            itemData = $item.data();
            if(itemData.price <= priceCriteria){
                $item.animate({opacity: 1});
                itemData.matching = true;
            }else{
                $item.animate({opacity: 0.5});
                itemData.matching = false;
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="banner"> <img src="images/candybarbanner.jpg" width="800" height="140" alt="The Candy Bar Banner" id="hero"/> </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Here at the Candy Bar we're only interested in providing the highest quality candies. Please look at our select gourmet pieces below, select favorites or see how much you want to buy!</p>
    <article id="gallery" class="post">
      <div id="candy1" class="candy" draggable="true"><img src="images/chocolatecaramel.jpg" width="100" height="124" alt="Chocolate Caramel Bite" />
        <figcaption>Chocolate Caramel<br />
          <span class="price">$1</span></figcaption>
      </div>
      <div id="candy2" class="candy" draggable="true"><img src="images/gumdrops.jpg" width="156" height="125" alt="Gum Drops"/>
        <figcaption>Gum Drops<br />
          <span class="price">$2</span></figcaption>
      </div>
      <div id="candy3" class="candy" draggable="true"><img src="images/truffles.jpg" width="156" height="125" alt="French Truffles"/>
        <figcaption>French Truffles<br />
          <span class="price">$3</span></figcaption>
      </div>
      <div id="candy4" class="candy" draggable="true" style="clear: both"><img src="images/saltwatertaffy.jpg" width="148" height="150" alt=""/>
        <figcaption>Saltwater Taffy<br />
          <span class="price">$4</span></figcaption>
      </div>
      <div id="candy5" class="candy" draggable="true"><img src="images/Peanut-Butter-Cup.jpg" width="100" height="150" alt="Peanut Butter Cups"/>
        <figcaption>Peanut Butter Cups<br />
          <span class="price">$5</span></figcaption>
      </div>
      <div id="candy6" class="candy" draggable="true"><img src="images/cinnamonbears.jpg" width="183" height="150" alt="Cinnamon Bears"/>
        <figcaption>Cinnamon Bears<br />
          <span class="price">$6</span></figcaption>
      </div>
      <div id="candy7" class="candy" draggable="true" style="clear: both"><img src="images/toffee.jpg" width="170" height="150" alt="Toffee"/>
        <figcaption>Toffee<br />
          <span class="price">$7</span></figcaption>
      </div>
      <div id="candy8" class="candy" draggable="true"><img src="images/peanutbrittle.jpg" width="195" height="150" alt="Peanut Brittle"/>
        <figcaption>Peanut Brittle<br />
          <span class="price">$8</span></figcaption>
      </div>
    </article>
    <aside id="priceandfavorites">
      <div id="sliderdiv"> Price<br />
        <div>
          <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
            <input id="slider" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" value="10" onchange="printValue('slider','rangeValue')" />
            <br />
            <input id="rangeValue" type="text" size="2" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="favorites"> Favorites
        <p>Drag Favorites Here</p>
        <ul id="favs">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>
  </div>
  <footer><a href="##">Home</a> | <a href="##">Contact Us</a></footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The areas most specifically I'm having problems with are:

```
<script>
// Set price data for candy

    $('#candy1').data({ id:1, price:1 });
    $('#candy2').data({ id:2, price:2 });
    $('#candy3').data({ id:3, price:3 });
    $('#candy4').data({ id:4, price:4 });
    $('#candy5').data({ id:5, price:5 });
    $('#candy6').data({ id:6, price:6 });
    $('#candy7').data({ id:7, price:7 });
    $('#candy8').data({ id:8, price:8 });

// Link range to candy
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var theValue;

        $("#slider").change(function (){
            theValue = $('#rangeValue').val();
            filterItems(theValue);
        });
    });

    function filterItems(priceCriteria){
        $.each($('#gallery div'), function(i, item){
            $item = $(item); 
            itemData = $item.data();
            if(itemData.price <= priceCriteria){
                $item.animate({opacity: 1});
                itemData.matching = true;
            }else{
                $item.animate({opacity: 0.5});
                itemData.matching = false;
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

and:

```
<article id="gallery" class="post">
      <div id="candy1" class="candy" draggable="true"><img src="images/chocolatecaramel.jpg" width="100" height="124" alt="Chocolate Caramel Bite" />
        <figcaption>Chocolate Caramel<br />
          <span class="price">$1</span></figcaption>
      </div>
      <div id="candy2" class="candy" draggable="true"><img src="images/gumdrops.jpg" width="156" height="125" alt="Gum Drops"/>
        <figcaption>Gum Drops<br />
          <span class="price">$2</span></figcaption>
      </div>
      <div id="candy3" class="candy" draggable="true"><img src="images/truffles.jpg" width="156" height="125" alt="French Truffles"/>
        <figcaption>French Truffles<br />
          <span class="price">$3</span></figcaption>
      </div>
      <div id="candy4" class="candy" draggable="true" style="clear: both"><img src="images/saltwatertaffy.jpg" width="148" height="150" alt=""/>
        <figcaption>Saltwater Taffy<br />
          <span class="price">$4</span></figcaption>
      </div>
      <div id="candy5" class="candy" draggable="true"><img src="images/Peanut-Butter-Cup.jpg" width="100" height="150" alt="Peanut Butter Cups"/>
        <figcaption>Peanut Butter Cups<br />
          <span class="price">$5</span></figcaption>
      </div>
      <div id="candy6" class="candy" draggable="true"><img src="images/cinnamonbears.jpg" width="183" height="150" alt="Cinnamon Bears"/>
        <figcaption>Cinnamon Bears<br />
          <span class="price">$6</span></figcaption>
      </div>
      <div id="candy7" class="candy" draggable="true" style="clear: both"><img src="images/toffee.jpg" width="170" height="150" alt="Toffee"/>
        <figcaption>Toffee<br />
          <span class="price">$7</span></figcaption>
      </div>
      <div id="candy8" class="candy" draggable="true"><img src="images/peanutbrittle.jpg" width="195" height="150" alt="Peanut Brittle"/>
        <figcaption>Peanut Brittle<br />
          <span class="price">$8</span></figcaption>
      </div>
    </article>
```

Any help on what I might be missing would be very appreciated. Thank you

EDIT:

As suggested I tried moving the data portion into the rest of the function like so:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var theValue;

            $('#candy1').data({ id:1, price:1 });
            $('#candy2').data({ id:2, price:2 });
            $('#candy3').data({ id:3, price:3 });
            $('#candy4').data({ id:4, price:4 });
            $('#candy5').data({ id:5, price:5 });
            $('#candy6').data({ id:6, price:6 });
            $('#candy7').data({ id:7, price:7 });
            $('#candy8').data({ id:8, price:8 });

        $("#slider").change(function (){
            theValue = $('#rangeValue').val();
            filterItems(theValue);
        });
    });

    function filterItems(priceCriteria){
        $.each($('#gallery div'), function(i, item){
            $item = $(item); 
            itemData = $item.data();
            if(itemData.price <= priceCriteria){
                $item.animate({opacity: 1});
                itemData.matching = true;
            }else{
                $item.animate({opacity: 0.5});
                itemData.matching = false;
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Unfortunately it does not appear to fix anything.

EDIT 2:

I opened Google's developers tool and it's telling me that $ is not defined, did I forget to note something somewhere so that it knows it's dealing with jQuery?

EDIT 3:

I figured it was something stupid like that, that fixed it. Thank you all very much for your help.

Comment: a fiddle would be great to work with!!

Comment: You should put all your javascript code inside the `$(document).ready(function () {`.

Comment: What is the actual problem? What does not work?

Comment: When the slider is moved, the items labled candy1, candy2, candy3, etc, do not grey out based on the price listed in the data, which is the goal of the script.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code and check if it enter the `if(..)` statement?

Comment: It works for me here http://jsfiddle.net/ngn8mfhx/. Check your browser console for errors.

Comment: If the above is all of your code, you don't have jQuery loaded at all. [Make sure it's being loaded](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) because your code [appears to beworking correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/zax4f6pp/)

Comment: **$ is not defined** jQuery not Loaded. Include jQuery file reference with correct url/path.